# I need Alert When you reach nearest location (100 meter) of Added in your app

Tags: android

my Android app functionally is added current location and image in app using google mapv2 image and address store in server . now I want to alert when you reach in 100 meter in your added location in app. can you help me. thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create and monitor geofences.

**Create a geofence list:**

First, use `Geofence.Builder` to create a geofence, setting the desired radius, duration, and transition types for the geofence. For example, to populate a list object named mGeofenceList:

```
mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
    // Set the request ID of the geofence. This is a string to identify this
    // geofence.
    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())

    .setCircularRegion(
            entry.getValue().latitude,
            entry.getValue().longitude,
            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
    )
    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
    .build());
```

**Specify geofences and initial triggers:**

```
private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
    GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
    builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
    builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
    return builder.build();
}
```

**Define an Intent for geofence transitions:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService.class);
// We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when
// calling addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.
        FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**Add geofences:**

```
LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
            mGoogleApiClient,
            getGeofencingRequest(),
            getGeofencePendingIntent()
    ).setResultCallback(this);
```

**Handle Geofence Transitions:**

`GeofenceTransitionsIntentService` obtains the geofencing event from the intent, determines the type of Geofence transition(s), and determines which of the defined geofences was triggered. It then sends a notification as the output.

```
public class GeofenceTransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {
   ...
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
            String errorMessage = GeofenceErrorMessages.getErrorString(this,
                    geofencingEvent.getErrorCode());
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            return;
        }

        // Get the transition type.
        int geofenceTransition = geofencingEvent.getGeofenceTransition();

        // Test that the reported transition was of interest.
        if (geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER ||
                geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

            // Get the geofences that were triggered. A single event can trigger
            // multiple geofences.
            List triggeringGeofences = geofencingEvent.getTriggeringGeofences();

            // Get the transition details as a String.
            String geofenceTransitionDetails = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(
                    this,
                    geofenceTransition,
                    triggeringGeofences
            );

            // Send notification and log the transition details.
            sendNotification(geofenceTransitionDetails);
            Log.i(TAG, geofenceTransitionDetails);
        } else {
            // Log the error.
            Log.e(TAG, getString(R.string.geofence_transition_invalid_type,
                    geofenceTransition));
        }
    }
```

Checkout this official document for [Creating and Monitoring Geofences](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html#HandleGeofenceTransitions) to get detailed information about it.

Comment: I don't have sample code. But read that developer document carefully, you will surely get idea about implementation.

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple. You implement the Localistener class and use the distanceTo function there to check the  distance and then use notificationmanager. I actually cannot understand the question properly .Do you only want the location distance or something else... Can you tell clearly?

Comment: sir, I want alert when you reach added location in app. ex. you add airport Ahmedabad in app than image its store in app. now you reach nearest (approximately 100 meter) airport Ahmedabad than I need a popup means alert dialogue . I hope you understand my question